How to store CA private keys on custom PKI app
I`m currently making a Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) app in Spring Boot. It`s a student project so have in mind that I don`t have dedicated hardware for storing private keys and stuff.
I planned on storing private keys for each CA inside a separate .pem file as I found out it`s the best format for storing any kind of encrypted or secret data and protecting that file with the ACL (read-only for the PKI app). I would need to have a lookup file or database table which will contain the certificate serial number and private key as a pair so it would be possible to find the private key for the desired CA when signing of the new certificate is needed. I just wanted to check if this kind of approach is any good and take any suggestions.
